# How can I split a window in two in windows api

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, direct3d

The basic idea is to split the window in 2 so I can paint with 2 pictures with GDI or eventually use Direct3D to display 2 different scenes. How can i achieve this only with windows API

Comment: Please take a look around StackOverflow to get a feeling for how the site works and what useful questions look like; also read the FAQ please.

Comment: Kerrek you are not helping... the whole point of the site is to lend a hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is create 3 windows, a parent window and two non-dialog child window's using CreateWindowEx with the WS_CHILD flag for the babiges, and just rigging the dimensions and position to make room for halfsies in the windows!

I came up with this source example quickly:

http://codepaste.dev7studios.com/item/t7mvpvv3w

Comment: the link is not working.

Comment: can't see the code, the page won't open

Answer (score 3):

Make 2 separate windows with CreateWindow.